# Create a Build Pipeline for Console Application with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, build-definition

Requesting your support in Create a build pipeline for Console Application. Please refer below build definition which we have defined for our application which contains 4 projects, we have configured drop location for publish artifacts and successfully configured the build definition.

[image]

We have configured as per the build definition, while we are creating release definition we are unable to find zip file and noticed the zip file has been created in build definition under drop folder.

[image]

Please provide you precise description of configuring build definition and release definition for a Console Application.

Comment: Why do you need a zip file?

Answer (score 1):

You could add artifact directly in your release definition. An artifact is a deployable component of your application. It is typically produced through a Continuous Integration or a build process. Release Management can deploy artifacts.

[image]

Check the link below for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=vsts